# Rails 5 test global setup and teardown (minitest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am using the out of the box, vanilla test suite for Rails 5 beta. I am wondering if anyone has figured out how to run a global setup, and tear down.

The reason this is required to I am spinning up a in memory Elasticsearch cluster before any test begins and stop the cluster once the tests are done.

Rspec is not an option.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? Answer given below by @BoraMa surely does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Under Minitest (which is the default testing environment in Rails 4+), to get the "global setup" behavior, **simply run anything in your `test_helper.rb`** (outside the tests themselves or any `setup` methods), i.e. in the file where you load your testing environment from. The test helper is usually required in the tests, so its code is run once before any tests.

For a "global teardown", Minitest provides the **[`Minitest.after_run` method](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest.rb#L73)**. Anything inside its block will be run once after all tests are finished (it uses the program exit hook). Place it e.g. in the `test_helper` again. For this to work you need to `require 'minitest/autorun'` at the beginning of the test helper file.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work with rails 5. See the repo here - https://github.com/paneer-tikka/foo

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? Setup, teardown, both? Also there is no code in the repo you linked.

Comment: Sorry, updated the repo now. The teardown with Minitest.after_run does not get called at all. See test_helper.rb line 14. I'm expecting that to be called at the end of the execution of "rails test". What am I missing?

Comment: The `after_run` feature works only if you use the ["autorun" minitest feature](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#featuresproblems) to run all the tests, i.e. if you `include 'minitest/autorun'` instead of just 'minitest'. Just tried it successfully on your repo. Will update the answer.

Comment: Yep, that works, except it is `require "minitest/autorun"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`test/test_helper.rb`

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    do_something
  end

  teardown do
    do_something
  end
end
```

Defined in the [`ActiveSupport::Testing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c70791470fc517deb7c640bead9f1b47efb5539/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb) module.

Comment: Worked like a charm with Rails 6!